How to say "later bedtime"?
I am watching a cartoon, in which a dentist threatens a bunch of children that he will rat them out on a stolen magazine unless the children return it. If the dentist tells their parents, they will lose "their later bedtime".
Je regarde un dessin animé. À un certain moment un dentiste, furieux que des enfants aient chapardé un magazine à son bureau, menace de révéler ceci devant leurs parents, qui pourraient ensuite leur enlever "their later bedtime".
How do you say "later bedtime"?
Comment traduire "later bedtime"? Il s'agit de permettre à ses enfants de se coucher à une heure plus avancée, mais pour une version traduite du dessin animé lui-même il faut une traduction plus concise.
Is this a culturally specific thing? Is it normal in French-speaking countries to give your children the privilege of staying up a little bit late as a reward?
Cette pratique est-elle particulière à certaines cultures? Est-ce normal dans les pays francophones de récompenser son enfant en lui octroyant le privilège de rester éveillé un peu tard?

Qui pourraient ensuite leur interdire de veiller [plus longtemps]. The absolute veiller was understood as later bedtime in my own family.

Late (later) bedtime & early(earlier) bedtime are English phrases that don't have a word for word translation in French and you have to expand  when translating. In the situation you describe I'd just use se coucher, not mentioning the noun "time", it is obvious what we are talking about.

Si je le dis à vos parents il pourraient vous interdire de vous coucher (de veiller) plus tard.

(Having interdire rather than enlever l'autorisation makes the sentence a wee bit shorter.
Same in this sentence "Later bedtime on Friday night" (as a reward idea) → Se coucher plus tard le vendredi soir.
"Earlier bedtimes may help teens get more sleep" → Se coucher plus tôt peut aider les ados à dormir plus.
But there are cases where heure de coucher, the literal translation of "bedtime", would be better. A few examples:
Advice on an occasional later bedtime → Quelques conseils pour retarder l'heure du coucher.
How to adjust your day for a later bedtime → Comment régler sa journée pour retarder l'heure du coucher.


Is it normal in French-speaking countries to give your children the privilege of staying up a little bit late as a reward?

This is more  an educational question than a language question. Would some parents in France allow their children to stay up later on some particular occasions? I'd say most certainly, but surely some parents would also object.
Found on this blog : Naitre et grandir, one of the rewards on a motivation chart is Se coucher 5 minutes plus tard (→ going to bed 5 minutes later).

Later bedtime : une heure de coucher plus tardive.

Il y a une source ou peut-être une explication de l'usage selon le contexte ?
